# Who is meant by "enemy" and "conspiracy" in Kennedy's speech?

Tags: united-states

President John F. Kennedy had a speech on April 27, 1961; famously called "[THE PRESIDENT AND THE PRESS](https://www.jfklibrary.org/archives/other-resources/john-f-kennedy-speeches/american-newspaper-publishers-association-19610427)". In that speech, he mentions a hidden enemy with concealed acts. **Who is it?**

The President have referred to the issue mainly in this part:

> Today no war has been declared--and however fierce the struggle may
>   be, it may never be declared in the traditional fashion. Our way of
>   life is under attack. Those who make themselves our enemy are
>   advancing around the globe. The survival of our friends is in danger.
>   And yet no war has been declared, no borders have been crossed by
>   marching troops, no missiles have been fired.
>
> If the press is awaiting a declaration of war before it imposes the
>   self-discipline of combat conditions, then I can only say that no war
>   ever posed a greater threat to our security. If you are awaiting a
>   finding of "clear and present danger," then I can only say that the
>   danger has never been more clear and its presence has never been more
>   imminent.
>
> It requires a change in outlook, a change in tactics, a change in
>   missions--by the government, by the people, by every businessman or
>   labor leader, and by every newspaper. For we are opposed around the
>   world by a monolithic and ruthless conspiracy that relies primarily on
>   covert means for expanding its sphere of influence--on infiltration
>   instead of invasion, on subversion instead of elections, on
>   intimidation instead of free choice, on guerrillas by night instead of
>   armies by day. It is a system which has conscripted vast human and
>   material resources into the building of a tightly knit, highly
>   efficient machine that combines military, diplomatic, intelligence,
>   economic, scientific and political operations.
>
> Its preparations are concealed, not published. Its mistakes are
>   buried, not headlined. Its dissenters are silenced, not praised. No
>   expenditure is questioned, no rumor is printed, no secret is revealed.
>   It conducts the Cold War, in short, with a war-time discipline no
>   democracy would ever hope or wish to match.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's worth noting that the speech was delivered on April 27, 1961 after the [failed Bay of Pigs invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion) (April 17–20, 1961) which was "intended to overthrow the increasingly communist government of Fidel Castro".

Here's an analysis from [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/11/learning/lesson-plans/analyzing-the-relationship-between-the-press-and-the-president-a-lesson-plan.html):

> Delivered after the failed Bay of Pigs invasion (an attempt to overthrow Fidel Castro in Cuba), the speech focuses on his view of the “dilemma faced by a free and open society in a cold and secret war.”
>
> [ ... ]
>
> This speech is given in the midst of the Cold War; in fact, just a little more than a week after the failed Bay of Pigs invasion. Kennedy felt that leaks in the press had, in part, led to the military failure in Cuba. As a result, Kennedy organizes his words around a desire to reconcile two somewhat contradictory needs: “the need for far greater public information; and [the] need for far greater official secrecy.”

Another [excerpt from his speech](https://www.jfklibrary.org/archives/other-resources/john-f-kennedy-speeches/american-newspaper-publishers-association-19610427) probably provides a clearer context.

> In time of war, the government and the press have customarily joined in an effort based largely on self-discipline, to **prevent unauthorized disclosures to the enemy**. In time of "clear and present danger," the courts have held that even the privileged rights of the First Amendment must yield to the public's need for national security.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Hence, the enemy that Kennedy was referring to was Communism.

Answer (score 9):

It seems pretty obvious that he was talking about the Soviet/communist camp, especially given the last sentence "It conducts the Cold War [...]"